# How can I use the Dolphin 70E's hardware scanner in an app?

Tags: hardware, barcode

I have a Dolphin 70E that has a hardware scanner. I would like to use this in a an app, but ZXing always uses the camera in the device instead. I have looked into Google Goggles as well, but running into the same issue here.

Honeywell has provided an example app that does exactly what I want, but I can't seem to find any documentation.

Comment: I have an experience with similar product (Android barcode scanner), and AFAIK, you don't need any "barcode scanner" app. The hardware scanner will automatically decode the barcode *as text input* (just like someone typing using keyboard). I don't know though with Dolphin device, but have you tried that?

Comment: You'll probably get voted down or put on hold as off topic since you're asking an android development question here.  I am curious about barcode scanning in android too, and I thought Andrew's answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That is how I was expecting the device to respond and input the text automatically. However the laser does not even come on when the button is pressed so I am a little lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found on the [Honeywell knowledge base](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/CatalogDocuments/PWRTLS-AND-UG%20Rev%20B.pdf).

Under **Power Tools > ScanWedge** there is a toggle to enable/disable. When ScanWedge is enabled, the scanner buttons work as expected in any application (basically just keyboard input).